# CakePHP generate pdf then send as email attachment

Tags: php, email, cakephp, pdf, cakephp-2.4

I'm using the TCPDF library to create invoices in my CakePHP application. If I go to `/invoices/view/1` my view.ctp includes the code to generate and display the pdf in the browser. I want to add the ability to send the pdf as an email attachment so I created the action `/invoices/send_invoice` and copied the code from view.ctp into an email template.

Now where I'm stuck, I don't know how to have the PDF generated first before attaching it. 
At the end of my view.ctp page template I use

```
$pdf->Output(APP . 'File/pdf_invoices' . DS . 'invoice-'.$invoice['Invoice']['id'].'.pdf', 'I');
```

which sends the pdf to view in browser without creating the file. I can save the file if I use 'F' or 'FI' as the last parameter to $pdf->Output() but it's not guaranteed that the user will view the invoice before trying to send it as an email.

In my send_invoice action I need to have the pdf generated as a file in order to attach it with:

```
$email->attachments(APP . 'File/pdf_invoices' . DS . 'invoice-'.$invoice['Invoice']['id'].'.pdf');
```

having the code that generates the pdf file in my email template means the file doesn't exist yet when I try to attach it. Is there some way to attach the file from the email template itself? I was thinking maybe I can write a function on my Invoice model to generate the pdf but I want to use some View Helpers (like the Number helper) to format my data. Can I execute the code in a view and then return to the controller/action without displaying the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by creating a view object, then manually calling the functions you need to get it to render properly.

```
 $view = new View(null, false);
 $view->set(//set view data here like normal);
 $view->viewPath = 'pdf';  //folder to look in in Views directory
 $output = $view->render('pdf', 'pdf');  //layout name and view name
```

Then just save the output, or use it however you need.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to attach the pdf with this line `$email->attachments(array('invoice-'.$invoice_id.'.pdf'=>array('data'=>$output)));`

Answer (score 2):

**Cakephp Email with PDF Attachment and PDF generation with CakePDF plugin**

Step1: Installing and Setup CakePDF

Step 2: Configuration

Step 3: App Controller Configuration

```
App::uses('CakePdf', 'CakePdf.Pdf');
public $components = array("Email","RequestHandler");
```

Step 4: Controller Code for your CakePHP

```
    // PDF Generation code
    $this->set('extraparams', $categories);

    $this->pdfConfig = array(
        'orientation' => 'portrait',
        'filename' => 'invoice_'. $orderID
    );

    $CakePdf = new CakePdf();
    $CakePdf->viewVars(array('extraparams' => $categories));
    $CakePdf->template('confirmpdf', 'default');
    //get the pdf string returned
    $pdf = $CakePdf->output();
    //or write it to file directly


    $pdf = $CakePdf->write(APP . 'webroot'. DS .'files' . DS . 'orders' . DS . 'order_'.$orderID.'.pdf');
    $pdf = APP . 'webroot'. DS .'files' . DS . 'orders' . DS . 'order_'.$orderID.'.pdf';
    // PDF Generation code

    return $pdf;
```

Very helpful link, just follow mentioned steps and your PDF are generating:

[Read More](http://rapidsol.blogspot.com/2013/11/cakephp-email-with-pdf-attachment-and.html)

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: @XaviLópez: thanks for suggestion, updated above - hope it will help more !

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, if you can use `wkhtmltopdf`, is to generate a temp pdf file, attach it and delete it.
`wkhtmltopdf` does the main job: It directly converts an html file to a pdf. The html is your view.